# EF-Core Eager Loading to a ViewModel

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-key-relationship

In my `ASP.NET Core 1.1` with `EF Core 1.1 app`, I've a scenario similar to the following: Parent table `PT` and child table `CH` have 1-1 FK-relationship. We need to get a few columns from certain records from `PT` table, and a few columns from associated records from the `CH` table. **Question**: How can I load these records to the following `ViewModel` using the following LINQ query? **Note**: I can have it done using regular LINQ Join etc but was curious as to how we can do it using `Eager Loading`

**ViewModel:**

```
public class PT_CH_ViewModel
{
Public int PTCol1 {get; set;}
Public string PTCol1 {get; set;}
Public float PTCol1 {get; set;}
....
Public int CHCol1 {get; set;}
Public string CHCol2 {get; set;}
....
}
```

**Controller:** Need to load `PT_CH_ViewModel` here and return it as a list

```
....
PT pt = _context.PT
                .Include(p => p.CH)
                .Where(p => p.PTcol == selectedID);
....
return View(???);
```

Comment: Hi, you can use automapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a navigation property for your CH entity. Once eager loaded, you can then access the navigation property's content.

```
public class PT
{
    public int Col1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual CH CH { get; set; } // optional, do not put [Required] attribute
}

public CH
{
    public int Col1 { get; set; }
    ...
    [Required] // CH table needs PT table for the 1-1 relationship
    public PT PT { get; set; }
}


PT_CH_ViewModel viewModel = new PT_CH_ViewModel()
{
    PTCol1 = pt.Col1,
    PTCol2 = pt.Col2,
    PTCol3 = pt.Col3,
    CHCol1 = pt.CH.Col1,
    CHCol2 = pt.CH.Col2
};


return View(viewModel);
```

Since you need it as a list, you can do something like:

```
var pts = _context.PT
                .Include(p => p.CH)
                .Where(p => p.PTcol == selectedID)
                .Select(pt => new PT_CH_ViewModel()
                {
                    PTCol1 = pt.Col1,
                    PTCol2 = pt.Col2,
                    PTCol3 = pt.Col3,
                    CHCol1 = pt.CH.Col1,
                    CHCol2 = pt.CH.Col2
                }).ToList();

return View(pts);
```

View:

```
@model List<PT_CH_ViewModel>
```

Comment: In the last block of your code: 1) did you mean `p.col1,...etc.` and not `pt.col1...etc.` 2) Do I still need to apply ToList() to `pts` or `pts` will be a list itself?

Comment: @nam it will return an `IEnumerable`. You can use `ToList()` if that's what you need. I intended to use `pt =>` instead of 'p =>'. Edited.